# Closed questions with high scores

Tags: discussion

For instance this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318645/javafx-or-swing/12565729#12565729

With a vote of over 110 and the top answer earning 100 votes, it seems that quite a number of users of the site don't consider it off topic at all. Shouldn't it have been automatically nominated for re-opening? Or even automatically re-opened?

Comment: Don't confuse *popularity* with being *on topic*. Also, what is on topic has changed over time; the question was on topic *6 years ago*, but is not on topic today.

Comment: The number of upvotes it has doesn't change the fact that it's blatantly looking for a recommendation.

Answer (score 7):

There are questions that turned out to be a magnet for so many opinionated answers that they basically broke the whole idea of the workings of the Q/A mechanics were good answers float to top.

None of the answers on that (now deleted) question are good. It is more a popularity contest where the users with best verbal skills got the votes. It has nothing to do with which framework/tool is more future proof. Besides that, if it is really helpful for the OP highly depends on the context of the OP. For future visitors there is not much to gain from that question, let alone the answers.

There are other venues, maybe reddit or quora, where these kind of opinion based exchanges of ideas will fly. In the Q/A format it doesn't and as such those question get closed and deleted when brought up on meta.

For posterity here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuNwP.jpg).